# $http.get returns string identical to test string but does not work

Tags: angularjs, json

I am attempting to use matt lewis's angular bootstrap calendar https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar - with database data, but I am pulling my hair out trying virtually every combination of JSON post, echo, stringify, parse, serialize and on and on.

I can get the calendar to display events with a hard coded string, but when I try to get the string with $http.get it won't work. I went to great pains to ensure this string was identical to the hard coded one, but still no go. I know this is a lot of code but I don't know how else to show my problem. Please help!

### index.html (calendar page)

```
<!doctype tml ng-app="mwl.calendar.docs">
      <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/interact.js/1.2.4/interact.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.0.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/jkbrzt/rrule/v2.1.0/lib/rrule.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/3.0.25/js/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/js/angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app/calendarappBk2.js"></script>    
        <script src="helpers.js"></script>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker/3.0.25/css/colorpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/dist/css/angular-bootstrap-calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>
      <body>

    <div ng-controller="KitchenSinkCtrl as vm">
      <h2 class="text-center">{{ vm.calendarTitle }}</h2>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <div class="btn-group">

            <button
              class="btn btn-primary"
              mwl-date-modifier
              date="vm.viewDate"
              decrement="vm.calendarView">
              Previous
            </button>
            <button
              class="btn btn-default"
              mwl-date-modifier
              date="vm.viewDate"
              set-to-today>
              Today
            </button>
            <button
              class="btn btn-primary"
              mwl-date-modifier
              date="vm.viewDate"
              increment="vm.calendarView">
              Next
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br class="visible-xs visible-sm">

        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'year'">Year</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'month'">Month</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'week'">Week</label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="vm.calendarView" uib-btn-radio="'day'">Day</label>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <br>

      <mwl-calendar
        events="vm.events"
        view="vm.calendarView"
        view-title="vm.calendarTitle"
        view-date="vm.viewDate"
        on-event-click="vm.eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
        on-event-times-changed="vm.eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
        cell-is-open="vm.isCellOpen"
        day-view-start="06:00"
        day-view-end="22:59"
        day-view-split="30"
        cell-modifier="vm.modifyCell(calendarCell)">
      </mwl-calendar>

      <br><br><br>

      <h3 id="event-editor">
        Edit events
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary pull-right"
          ng-click="vm.addEvent()">
          Add new
        </button>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </h3>

      <table class="table table-bordered">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Primary color</th>
            <th>Secondary color</th>
            <th>Starts at</th>
            <th>Ends at</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="event in vm.events track by $index">
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="event.title">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" colorpicker type="text" ng-model="event.color.primary">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" colorpicker type="text" ng-model="event.color.secondary">
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  readonly
                  uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
                  ng-model="event.startsAt"
                  is-open="event.startOpen"
                  close-text="Close" >
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'startOpen', event)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </p>
              <div
                uib-timepicker
                ng-model="event.startsAt"
                hour-step="1"
                minute-step="15"
                show-meridian="true">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="input-group" style="max-width: 250px">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  readonly
                  uib-datepicker-popup="dd MMMM yyyy"
                  ng-model="event.endsAt"
                  is-open="event.endOpen"
                  close-text="Close">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-default"
                    ng-click="vm.toggle($event, 'endOpen', event)">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </p>
              <div
                uib-timepicker
                ng-model="event.endsAt"
                hour-step="1"
                minute-step="15"
                show-meridian="true">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                class="btn btn-danger"
                ng-click="vm.events.splice($index, 1)">
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>

      </body>
    </html>
```

### calendarappBk2.js (ajax)

```
<?php

    $DB_HOST = 'localhost';
    $DB_USER = 'amsdev1';
    $DB_PASS = 'Toygoat@8';
    $DB_NAME = 'tcl3ams';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);

    $query="SELECT title, color, startsAt, endsAt, recursOn, draggable, resizable, actions from calendar";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    $arr = array();
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $json_response = "[";
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arr[] = $row;
            $json_response = $json_response.'{title: "'.$row["title"].'", ';
            $json_response = $json_response.'color: '.$row["color"].', ';
            $json_response = $json_response.'startsAt: "'.$row["startsAt"].'", ';
            $json_response = $json_response.'endsAt: "'.$row["endsAt"].'", ';
            $json_response = $json_response."recursOn: '".$row["recursOn"]."', ";
            $json_response = $json_response.'draggable: '.$row["draggable"].', ';
            $json_response = $json_response.'resizeable: '.$row["resizable"].', ';
            $json_response = $json_response.'actions: '.$row["actions"].'}, ';

        }
        $json_response = substr($json_response,0,strlen($json_response)-2);
        $json_response = $json_response."]";

    }
    //header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
    //header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

    //$json_response = json_encode($arr);

    echo json_encode($json_response);
    /*
    $ch = curl_init('/ams/index.html');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_response);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_response))
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    */
    ?>
```

### calendarappBk2.js (controller app)

```
    angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs', ['mwl.calendar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'colorpicker.module']);
    angular
      .module('mwl.calendar.docs') //you will need to declare your module with the dependencies ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']
      .controller('KitchenSinkCtrl', function($scope, $http, moment, alert, calendarConfig) {

        var vm = this;

        //These variables MUST be set as a minimum for the calendar to work

        vm.calendarView = 'month';
        vm.viewDate = new Date();
        var actions = [{
          label: '<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>',
          onClick: function(args) {
            alert.show('Edited', args.calendarEvent);
          }
        }, {
          label: '<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>',
          onClick: function(args) {
            alert.show('Deleted', args.calendarEvent);
          }
        }];

       $http.get("ajax/getCalendarBk2.php").success(function(data){
           vm.events = JSON.parse(data);
            window.alert(vm.events);
           });
     /* 
         vm.events = [{title: "Testerson", color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.info, startsAt: "2016-10-10 10:00:00", endsAt: "2016-10-10 11:00:00", recursOn: '', draggable: true, resizeable: true, actions: actions}, {title: "Anoter Testerson", color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.info, startsAt: "2016-10-12 11:00:00", endsAt: "2016-10-12 12:00:00", recursOn: '', draggable: true, resizeable: true, actions: actions}, {title: "This is a really long Testerson that occurs on every year", color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning, startsAt: "2016-10-14 13:00:00", endsAt: "2016-10-14 14:00:00", recursOn: 'year', draggable: true, resizeable: true, actions: actions}];
    */
        vm.isCellOpen = true;

        vm.addEvent = function() {
          vm.events.push({
            title: 'New event',
            startsAt: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
            endsAt: moment().endOf('day').toDate(),
            color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.important,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: true
          });
        };

        vm.eventClicked = function(event) {
          alert.show('Clicked', event);
        };

        vm.eventEdited = function(event) {
          alert.show('Edited', event);
        };

        vm.eventDeleted = function(event) {
          alert.show('Deleted', event);
        };

        vm.eventTimesChanged = function(event) {
          alert.show('Dropped or resized', event);
        };

        vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          $event.stopPropagation();
          event[field] = !event[field];
        };

      });
```

Comment: Tom you should edit your code structure, separate it to the controller, HTML, and ajax.

Comment: try to use then rather success callback. $http.get('/someUrl', config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

Comment: Right now, are you able to get proper data from server on $http request?

Comment: Never try to manually create json. In php you only need arrays and then `json_encode` will encode all at once

Comment: And `$http` does all the json parsing for you

Comment: Also note that javascript won't read that datetime format. You need to parse and convert to a date object once received in `$http` to meet calendar requirements

Comment: Liron, my code is separate. I only put it together here for the sake of posting it.

Comment: Aniruddha, I did try it just as you suggested. I still have it commented out in my original code. I took it out before I posted. I was already posting too much code.

Comment: Ravi, according to my dump of "data" with window.alert, yes. And in the exact format that works in the commented out vm.events =

Comment: charlietfl, I have tried that as shown in the commented code. The angular controller will only work with quotes around title:"title" and the date values like so, but not around the boolean and color values. The exact string it works with is shown in the commented vm.events =

Comment: charlietfl, my code results in the exact string I need according to the dump of data with windows.alert. it is formatted exactly like the commented code that works. I have tried it with and without JSON.parse. Without, it wraps quotes around everything and doesn't work. I have also tried stringify and serialize. This is the only way I can get it formatted like the only way I have gotten it to work, albeit hard coded.

Comment: chaarlietfl, the controller docs request that moment.js or it's date format is used. I have tried moment as well, but this date is formatted just like it formats. The plunker I went by uses moment as well. https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=kitchen-sink

Comment: charleitfl, I mispoke earlier. Without parsing, the string has all the quotes "escaped" ( \ preceding every ")

Comment: @charlietfl  Console.log reports several errors in angular-bootstrap-calendar-tpls.min.js. I will test with the hard coded vm.events.

Comment: escaped quotes aren't an issue if done by json_encode...browser will parse them properly

Comment: @charlietfl After working all day on the problem, the jist of it is: I need to pass an array object name as a property value. In other words, I need the value of the key:value to be a variable instead of a string. With ES5 there are many hoops to jump through I don't yet understand. Supposedly with ES6, I can use a "template literal"  or "template string" - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings -  The problem is really with the js code from angular bootstrap calendar. I am getting the json passed to the controller now. I will try to work on it after it's passed